# Is an Android select query cursor modified by a delete query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to find a way to notify a dependent component when certain rows are deleted, so can I issue a select query, obtain the cursor, then issue the delete or will that modify the original cursor? Is there a better approach altogether? This is what I'm referring to:

```
Cursor c = builder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder);
db.delete(table, selection, selectionArgs);
while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
    final String name = cursor.getString(0);
    // send notifications
}
c.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a content provider to access your database then you can use [ContentObservers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) which are designed exactly for this purpose:

When you retrieve data through a content provider you do so with a URI and it is this URI that you can use to notify ContentObserver's that the cursor has changed:

```
getContentResolver ().notifyChange (URI, null)
```

See the [javadocs for `notifyChange(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver%29) for more info:

I am afraid to say that you would have to write your own solution for this if you do not use content providers to access your data.

Comment: I am using a ContentProvider, but that does not give you any details on what was deleted besides the URI, correct? It does not even give you the information that a delete happened (only that the data corresponding to the URI was somehow modified).

Comment: You are right. In that case you can still use the notification system but instead of deleting the row, add a status column that you can set to deleted. This way you can query for rows with this flag when you get the notification.

Comment: @AbdullahJibaly why you need this ?(i'm assuming that you wana know every single row that you delete) ... maybe instead of deleting your contentprovider should mark row as deleted(add column isDeleted) ... then you can add another uri to proccess those "deleted" items and delete them premamently (i'm using such solution to sync local sqlite db with mssql) ...

Comment: @Selvin I have an external process which needs the data, so yes sort of similar to your use case. However I don't want to rely on that external process to tell me when it's ok to delete my data so I'll send a broadcast notification instead.

Answer (score 2):

the cursor is a data structure detached from the database. that is, modifying the database by whatever means, does not affect your already fetched cursor.

**Update**

This appeared to be wrong! .. sorry!

see the comments for details. thanks to @Selvin.

Comment: where did you read this? CursorWindow(CW) is fetched not whole Cursor ... i think if fx CW has only size 10 rows and whole result is 20 and you are in first CW then use delete then moveTo(11) will fail ... since driver will try to fetch data to CursorWindow ...

Comment: for a process to write to a sqlite database, it has to get an `EXCLUSIVE` lock. sqlite only gives one `EXCLUSIVE` lock and no other lock until the writing is finished. that means if some process is reading the database, sqlite waits until this process is finished reading and then gives the `EXCLUSIVE` lock to the one wanting to write.
this besides android `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()` opens a transaction in `EXCLUSIVE` mode.

http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29

Comment: that is, if the application is still reading the cursor, then no one else can write to the database file until the reading is over. then sqlite gives the `EXCLUSIVE` lock to the writer.
sorry @Selvin i had to split the comment in two for readability.

Comment: "that is, if the application is still reading the cursor, then no one else can write to the database file until the reading is over" ... actually it can ... and actualy your answer is **NOT** valid ... put this to onCreate of Activity to do some tests: http://pastebin.com/uC89dESQ  ... and you will get: 12-06 11:48:13.074: E/SQLiteConnection(8580): startPos 531443 > actual rows 531441

Comment: sorry ... this answer is not valid

Comment: this is whole code ... check logcat output:  http://pastebin.com/BYkPH9YZ ... Cursor is not storing data ... and this has nothing to do with locks ...

Comment: thanks @Selvin, you are right. i guess this is because it is the same process (application process) that reads and writes to the database file. i think locks apply when it is a different process only.